# Add extra steps to a function for testing purposes with monkeypatch

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a class like the following

```
class MyMixin:
  def base_dir(self):
    return "/mydir"

  def compute(self, origin, destination):
    pass  # execute some computation, not relevant
```

For testing purposes, I need to modify the `base_dir`. I used `monkeypatch`:

```
import MyMixin
@pytest.fixture
def global_computation(monkeypatch, temp_dir):
  with monkeypatch.context() as mp:
    mp.setattr(MyMixin, "base_dir", temp_dir)

    yield mp
```

That works well, and I would like to mock the `compute` function with another function that basically extends the original with a few extra lines of code.

Ideally, it would be something like this

```
def enhance_compute()
  result = compute()
  extra_step()
  return result
mp.setattr(MyMixin, "compute", enhance_compute)
```

However, I get an attribute error and I can't understand how to fix it.
Proceeding by steps, I tried to:

- Re-assign the same function (works fine)

  ```
  mp.setattr(MyMixin, "compute", MyMixin.compute)
  ```
- Create another function and assign it instead (raises the error):

  ```
  def compute(origin, destination):
    return MyMixin.compute(origin, destination)

  mp.setattr(MyMixin, "compute", compute)
  ```

  The error is the following

  > <Result ConstructorTypeError("<function _manip_config at 0x7ff7c0cac550> raised an error: compute() got multiple values for argument 'destination'")>.exit_code

I'm messing up with the arguments, but I'm not sure how I should pass them correctly.

Comment: At that point, what's left to actually be tested?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The actual function gets an exclusive lock on a file and writes something.
I need to test multiple invocations at the same time fail thanks to the lock. Adding a `time.sleep(1)` there would make it deterministic and straightforward to test.